# Equals and other methods for entity class in Node js

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node js. So, I have some basic doubts more related to OOP. I have defined one object as

```
function Person(name, age, address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}
```

Now, if I wanted to add methods for Person like equals(), hashCode(), etc., where can I do that?

I am familiar with JAVA language and there when we used to define a POJO class, we also sometimes used to add methods which worked on that.

Eventually, I wanted to do something like this

```
var p1 = new Person("person1", 18, "XYZ");
var p2 = new Person("person1", 18, "XYZ");

if(p1.equals(p2)) {
    .....
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: nodejs is not like java, for object comparison you will have to define uniqueness

Comment: You should read some tutorial, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javascript for something like this isn't complicated. You can simply define an `equals()` method on the prototype. Of course deciding how two objects are equal is a business logic problem that can be challenging.

For a simple idea of how to get started consider:

```
function Person(name, age, address) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
}
Person.prototype.equals = function(p) {
    // this ignores things you shouldn't like case sensitivity and string/number conversiosn
    return  this.name === p.name
            && this.age === p.age
            && this.address === p.address
}

var p1 = new Person("Mark", 30, "1234 Main Street")
var p1_1 = new Person("Mark", 30, "1234 Main Street")

var p2 = new Person("Steve", 29, "201 B Street")

p1.equals(p2)
// false

p1.equals(p1_1)
// true
```

There, of course, are a lot of difficult subtleties if you were doing this with real world data like whether `1234 Main Street === 1234 Main st.` and whether `John Smith === john h. smith`, but those transcend language issues.